# Paralelización de Multiplicación de Matrices mediante MPI en c++

Tags: c++

El problema en cuestión se trata de paralelizar una función de multiplicación de matrices con MPI en c++.

La función, sin paralelizar, es la siguiente:

```
void mMult(double** m1, double** m2, double** mRes)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < TAM; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < TAM; k++)
                mRes[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
}
```

La cuestión es que no se como funciona del todo MPI, y no se como hacerlo. La idea que tengo sería repartir la matriz 1 en grupos de filas para cada procesador. Así, repartiría la matriz y luego la volvería a recoger (si no me equivoco, sería con las funciones Scatter y Gather, pero no comprendo muy bien su funcionamiento).

### **ACTUALIZADO**

Código de la multiplicación

```
    void mMult(double** m1, double** m2, double** mRes)
{
    int rank, nPro;
    //int desde, hasta;
    //int filas;

    //MPI_Status status;    
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nPro); 
    //int num_pro = nPro - 1;

    double** m1Aux= new double*[TAM];   
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; ++i) 
        m1Aux[i] = new double[TAM];

    double** resAux= new double*[TAM];   
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; ++i) 
        resAux[i] = new double[TAM];

    inicializaMatriz(resAux);

    /*desde = rank * TAM/nPro;  
    hasta = (rank+1) * TAM/nPro;*/

    MPI_Scatter (m1, (TAM*TAM)/nPro, MPI_DOUBLE, m1Aux, (TAM*TAM)/nPro, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast (m2, TAM*TAM, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM / nPro; i++)
        for(int k = 0; k < TAM; k++)
            for(int j = 0; j < TAM; j++) 
                resAux[i][j] += m1Aux[i][k] * m2[k][j];

    MPI_Gather (resAux, (TAM/nPro)*TAM, MPI_DOUBLE, mRes, (TAM/nPro)*TAM, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; ++i) 
        delete [] resAux[i];
    delete [] resAux;

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; ++i) 
        delete [] m1Aux[i];
    delete [] m1Aux;
    }
```

Por alguna razón, sigue fallando. El error ahora es diferente, por lo que supongo que hay algún otro fallo que no soy capaz de ver.

Ejecución:

```
[ac_08@boe pruebasRaul]$ mpirun -np 2 ./mpi
Matriz A inicial:

14.5824 8.34719 13.2107 33.9339 22.3998 19.481
93.9394 29.2138 46.1168 64.5873 60.3853 37.3444
81.5901 9.73997 50.0579 12.4138 50.8575 25.8703
39.4942 12.1173 6.32202 25.9784 84.4658 76.6094
69.6866 27.2007 68.1807 91.0202 81.5895 97.2987
81.7301 96.1719 5.64592 94.9408 30.1058 28.0457

[boe:00673] * Process received signal *
[boe:00673] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[boe:00673] Signal code:  (128)
[boe:00673] Failing at address: (nil)
[boe:00673] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x35f340f7e0]
[boe:00673] [ 1] ./mpi(Z5mMultPPdS0_S0+0x1d9) [0x409eec]
[boe:00673] [ 2] ./mpi(Z11householderPPdS0_S0+0x2ec) [0x409ae8]
[boe:00673] [ 3] ./mpi(main+0x1c5) [0x4095e9]
[boe:00673] [ 4] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x35f2c1ed1d]
[boe:00673] [ 5] ./mpi() [0x409369]
[boe:00673] * End of error message *
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 673 on node boe.uv.es exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Código completo: [descomposicionQR_MPI.cpp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6rtvexd725b7p3/descomposicionQR_MPI.cpp?dl=0)

Comment: Échale un vistazo a este documento http://dis.um.es/~domingo/apuntes/AlgProPar/0607/PozueloMonfortP.pdf
Explica paso a paso el procedimiento y de forma muy clara. Si necesitas ayuda sobre algo concreto puedes postearlo.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿ Podrias mostrar los mensajes de error **exactos** que estás obteniendo ?

Comment: Has reservado memoria para la matriz resultado `mRes` previamente a la llamada de esta función?

Comment: Si, he reservado el espacio. De todas formas, he actualizado el código (tiene algunos cambios, pero en esencia es el mismo) y agregado el error que muestra

Comment: Podrías poner el resto del código para poder ejecutarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MPI_Scatter (m1, (TAM*TAM)/nPro, MPI_DOUBLE, m1Aux, (TAM*TAM)/nPro, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                    AQUI                               AQUI
```

¿Esas divisiones que estás haciendo son correctas? Piensa que en esa división estás truncando posibles valores:

```
TAM = 7
nPro = 5
valor = (TAM*TAM)/nPro = (7*7)/5 = 49/5 = 9 (la parte decimal se pierde)
valor*nPro = 9*5 = 45 != 49
```

Posiblemente sea este truncado el que hace que MPI detecte que parte de la memoria no está mapeada.

Comment: Lo comprobaré, gracias